# Android canvas draw a shape and move it from location A to B with animation duration

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-canvas

I have been looking around for hours on how to draw a shape and add a duration while it moves from point a to point b using canvas.

For example I have:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawCircle(40,40,40,paint);

    canvas.rotate(90, 50, 700);
}
```

This draws the circle and it rotates 90 degrees, moving to x,y location. The problem is it goes straight to the location. I would like mine to have a duration so the user sees it move from point A to point B on x or y axis.

Example:

The square will start at x_position:0 and u_position: 0. Then over 5 seconds it will move to location x_position:50 and y_position:50.

Is there a better way to accomplish this? I am assuming there is a much better way to accomplish this.

I have tried the following:

1. http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/09/introduction-to-2d-drawing-in-android.html#.VtlEM_krKUk
2. [Rotating Image on A canvas in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712652/rotating-image-on-a-canvas-in-android)
3. [How to draw a circle with animation in android with circle size based on a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381474/how-to-draw-a-circle-with-animation-in-android)

This one I believe is doing parts right however I could not implement this:

4. [How to make 2D graphic transition in android canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456322/how-to-make-2d-graphic-transition-in-android-canvas)

Comment: just use a `ValueAnimator` + `ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener`

Comment: I am new to using canvas, any chance you could answer the question with an example?

Comment: see http://pastebin.com/jjt0gPwD

Comment: I will try that out, thanks.

Comment: I tried to implement it however it does not seem to work.

Comment: you dont have to implement anything: just call `setContentView(new AnimationView(this));` in your `Activity#onCreate` to test it

Comment: I call it in my xml.

Comment: then learn how to write custom views that can be declared in xml layouts: http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/training/custom-views/create-view.html